# Diferentes tipos de datos en un array C

Tags: c

Actualmente estoy realizando un array de la siguiente forma:

```
char count[3][1] = {
    ["test"] = {0},
    ["prueba"] = {1},
    ["stack"] = {2}
    };
```

El problema es que al compilar no me lo reconoce bien, debido a que hay distintos tipos de datos.

Alguna idea para solucionarlo ?, es la primera vez que trabajo con arrays de este tipo.

Salutaciones y gracias.

Comment: Los caracteres se representan por comillas simples, ahí hay strings y enteros.. y evidentemente no podras hacerlo así porque TODOS los elementos del array deben de ser de dicho tipo. Porque no creas una clase que englobe esos 2 tipos de datos y haces un array unidimensional de ese objeto que has creado?

Comment: Lo que habia pensado era pasarlo todo como char y luego usar atoi para convertir los numeros a datos INT.

Comment: En C no es posible definir una matriz de esa manera. Si usas C++ hay forma de hacerlo, pero de otra forma. Si lo haces en C deberás implementar un TDA para almacenar esos datos.

Comment: Que solucion me recomendais entonces, en un caso de este tipo?

Comment: @akroma si quieres hacerlo así con string y enteros tendrás que unificarlos en un objeto, yo personalmente lo haría así.

Comment: ¿Vas a usar C puro? ¿C++? ¿Los índices van a ser siempre los mismos para cada elemento? Es decir, `test`, `prueba` y `stack` ¿son arbitrarios? Si vas a usar C entonces tendrás que usar una estructura en el primer caso, un TDA en el segundo. ¿Qué harás? Edito: Aquí tienes información sobre lo que es un TDA (primer resultado de google buscando por "TDA C"): https://sites.google.com/site/programacioniiuno/temario/unidad-2---tipo-abstracto-de-dato

Comment: Gracias chicos, ya lo he solucionado, basicamente he rehecho el array basando mis indices en una funcion numerica.

Comment: Deberías entonces publicar la solución como respuesta y marcar dicha respuesta como solución. Así aportarás tu granito de arena en SO

Comment: para marcar la solucion como lo hago?

Comment: @akroma , debes nombrar a una persona para que sepa que le has hablado (sólo nos llegan notificaciones en los comentarios a nuestras respuestas). Para marcar la solución primero debes redactar la respuesta y cómo lo has solucionado. Aún no tienes suficiente reputación para marcar tu propia respuesta como correcta de manera inmediata, debes esperar 48 horas antes de poder hacerlo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

No se puden mezclar tipos distintos en un array en C. Además, tampoco es esa la sintaxis correcta. Lo que sugiero, es definir una estructura con dos campos y luego un **array** de estructuras como muestro a continuación:

```
struct asociacion {
   char nombre [10];
   int valor;
};

struct asociacion count [3] = {
    {"test", 0},
    {"prueba", 1},
    {"stack", 2}
};
```

> **Luego,**
>
> count [2].nombre daría "stack"
>   count [1].valor daría 1

Podría responder mejor si supiera el objetivo del **array**